# how to get Apache Cordova (Phonegap) version of specific project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am new to Cordova and have a couple of projects in my eclipse's workspace.
Because I used different versions of Cordova from which I generate different projects (through CLI),

- How can I get the Cordova target for each project?

Calling

```
cordova -v
```

in each project folder, returns always the same

**3.5.0-0.2.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a batch file called version for instance at **platforms/android/cordova**,
Clicking on it would return the version of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cordova info` to get all details of the project. `cordova -v` will give installed version. 
you need to navigate to your project directory `E:\workplace\cordova_project` and then use `cordova info` . hope this helps.!

Comment: thanks but I get this: Collecting Data...


Node version: v0.10.28

Cordova version: 0.21.2

while I would expect something like 3.x